# SOAP Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I'm having a hard time understanding this error, and also finding an answer online. I am trying to consume an API in Postman from "correios", and I'm getting this error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: elemento inesperado (uri:"http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/", local:"codigoObjeto"). Os elementos esperados são &lt;{}codigoObjeto> </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Translating:**

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/", local:"codigoObjeto"). The expected elements are &lt;{}codigoObjeto>
```

This is the body for the POST request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <consultarObjetoPostado xmlns="http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/">
        <codigoObjeto>AB123456789BR</codigoObjeto>
    </consultarObjetoPostado>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I don't understand if the error is simply that the `<codigoObjeto>` is written wrong, and needs to be written as `<{}codigoObjeto>` or something else, because if I write as `<{}codigoObjeto>` it shows another error, like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in content after '&lt;' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,10] </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I really don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be in the namespace:

```
<consultarObjetoPostado xmlns="http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/">
    <!-- Element codigoObjeto belongs to the default namespace "http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/" -->
    <codigoObjeto>AB123456789BR</codigoObjeto>
</consultarObjetoPostado>
```

To remove `codigoObjeto` from the default namespace on the XML level it would be needed either to provide a namespace prefix:

```
<ns:consultarObjetoPostado xmlns:ns="http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/">
    <codigoObjeto>AB123456789BR</codigoObjeto>
</ns:consultarObjetoPostado>
```

Or provide an empty namespace on the element level:

```
<consultarObjetoPostado xmlns="http://service.objetopostado.cws.correios.com.br/">
    <codigoObjeto xmlns="">AB123456789BR</codigoObjeto>
</consultarObjetoPostado>
```

The client implementation may differ depending on the languages and frameworks used to build and to send the request.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried both solutions you presented, the second one worked, it doesn't show no errors. The strange thing that is happening now is that the <codigoObjeto> returns nothing. Maybe still something is wrong?

Comment: That's difficult to tell. Could you share the endpoint called? Or if that's not possible the response from the server?

Comment: Thank you the solution with empty namespace work for me !